# Add a background image for Custom Post Type archives page

Tags: images, uploads, admin-menu

I have a Custom Post Type "Vacancies". I have successfully created a Sub Menu Item in the admin menu "Background". I would like to show a file upload form to allow the admin the ability to upload a background image that will then be used for the archive-vacancies.php template. here is what I have so far:

[image]

```
/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    // add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=vacancies', 'Background Image', 'Background', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options');
}

/** Step 2. */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }

    wp_enqueue_media(); 

    ?>

    <h3>Background Image</h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="coverimage">Background Image</label>
            </th>

            <td>
                <img class="user-cover-image" id="user-cover-image-preview" src="<?php //echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'coverimage', $user->ID ) ); ?>" style="width:150px;"><br />

                <input type="text" name="coverimage" id="coverimage" value="" class="regular-text" />
                <input type='button' class="user-cover-image button-primary" value="Upload Image" id="uploadimage"/><br />

                <span class="description">Please upload a background image for the Vancancies Archive page.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am needing a way to upload an image and it be associated with the custom post type. I think I might have just found a solution. A plugin to add images to Categories or Tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is resolved with this plugin "Categories Images"